# How to build a checkbox tree with Richfaces?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, tree, richfaces

I want to build a checkbox tree with richfaces.

I saw [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeSelectionCheckbox.jsf) a sample with another jsf implemetation.

I want to have a similar functionality.

is it possible? How?

Comment: RichFaces has a `<rich:tree>` component. See also [showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=tree&skin=blueSky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure RichFaces will be able to help you with that, but [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) surely [will](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree).

Add the JAR to your project as instructed on the [project page](http://omnifaces.org), then create in your bean an implementation of [TreeModel](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/model/tree/TreeModel.html).

Here is the example from the showcase, using the provided [`ListTreeModel`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/model/tree/ListTreeModel.html):

```
private TreeModel<ExampleEntity> tree;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    tree = new ListTreeModel<ExampleEntity>();
    tree.addChild(new ExampleEntity(1L, "One"))
            .addChild(new ExampleEntity(2L, "Two")).getParent()
            .addChild(new ExampleEntity(3L, "Three")).getParent()
            .getParent()
        .addChild(new ExampleEntity(4L, "Four"))
            .addChild(new ExampleEntity(5L, "Five"));
}
```

Then, on your XHTML page, you can create your custom markup for the tree, here is an example using an HTML list with checkboxes:

```
 <o:tree id="tree" value="#{treeBean.tree}" var="exampleEntity" varNode="node">
    <o:treeNode>
        <ul>
            <o:treeNodeItem>
                <li>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{exampleEntity.value}" />
                    <o:treeInsertChildren />
                </li>
            </o:treeNodeItem>
        </ul>
    </o:treeNode>
</o:tree>
```

Then, for the collapsible effect you'll have to do some JavaScript, or reuse some of those [that](https://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/) [already](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryTree) [exists](http://homework.nwsnet.de/news/ea21_turn-nested-lists-into-a-collapsible-tree-with-jquery).

Comment: Good for Omnifaces but in my case, it is not allowed to use another JSF implementation except Richfaces

Comment: OmniFaces is not another JSF implementation, it's not even a Richfaces competitor, it's just a library to help everyday tasks with JSF 2.0. Please, read the project page and see what's it all about. :)

Comment: Even more, RichFaces is also not a JSF implementation at all.